# Split one file into multiple file using PIG script

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pipe delimited text file say abc.txt. which has different number of columns in different records. Number of columns in a record can be 100,80,70,60. I need to split abc.txt based on 3rd column value. If third column has value "A" , then that record will go to A.txt, if "B" then B.txt. Need to write a PIG script.

Answer (score 0):

```
abc = LOAD 'abc.txt' using PigStorage('|');
```

Assuming you have the 3rd column in all the records, `SPLIT` using the positional notation. It starts from **`0`**, so the third column will be **`$2`**.

```
SPLIT abc into a_records if $2 == 'A', b_records if $2 == 'B';
```

Then store the results, also note that `STORE` does not accept filenames as path.

```
STORE a_records into 'A_DIR' using PigStorage('|');
STORE b_records into 'B_DIR' using PigStorage('|');
```